# Reuse parameter value across different tasks in Airflow

Tags: airflow

How do I reuse a value that is calculated on the DAG run between tasks?

I'm trying to generate a timestamp in my DAG and use it in several tasks. So far I tried setting a Variable and a params value - nothing works, it's unique per each task run.

Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.athena import AWSAthenaOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.glue import AwsGlueJobOperator

default_args = {
    "sla": timedelta(hours=1),
}

config = Variable.get("config", deserialize_json=True)
athena_output_bucket = config["athena_output_bucket"]
glue_db = config["glue_db"]
bucket = config["bucket"]
region = config["region"]


def get_snapshot_timestamp(time_of_run=None):
    if not time_of_run:
        time_of_run = datetime.now()

    timestamp = time_of_run.timestamp() * 1000
    return str(int(timestamp))


class TemplatedArgsGlueOperator(AwsGlueJobOperator):
    template_fields = ("script_args",)


table = "my_table"

with DAG(
    "my-table-export",
    default_args=default_args,
    description="Export my table from DynamoDB to S3",
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    params={
        "snapshot_ts": get_snapshot_timestamp(),
        "athena_output_location": f"s3://{athena_output_bucket}/{table}",
        "table": table,
    },
) as dag:
    my_table_export_to_s3 = TemplatedArgsGlueOperator(
        task_id="my_table_export_to_s3",
        job_name="my-table-export-to-s3",
        num_of_dpus=2,
        region_name=region,
        script_args={"--snapshot_ts": "{{ params.snapshot_ts }}"},
    )

    add_new_partition = AWSAthenaOperator(
        task_id="add_new_partition",
        query="""
          ALTER TABLE {{ params.table }} ADD PARTITION (snapshot_ts = '{{ params.snapshot_ts }}')
          LOCATION 's3://{{ var.json.config.bucket }}/{{ params.table }}/snapshot_ts={{ params.snapshot_ts }}'
        """,
        database=glue_db,
        output_location="{{ params.athena_output_location }}",
    )

    update_latest_view = AWSAthenaOperator(
        task_id="update_latest_view",
        query="""
          CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW {{ params.table }}_latest AS
          SELECT * from {{ params.table }}
          WHERE snapshot_ts = '{{ params.snapshot_ts }}'
        """,
        database=glue_db,
        output_location="{{ params.athena_output_location }}",
    )


my_table_export_to_s3 >> add_new_partition >> update_latest_view
```

I want `snapshot_ts` to be the same across all three tasks, but it's different. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible via xcom. xCom is used precisely for exchanging information between various tasks. To quote

> XComs let tasks exchange messages, allowing more nuanced forms of
> control and shared state. The name is an abbreviation of
> “cross-communication”. XComs are principally defined by a key, value,
> and timestamp, but also track attributes like the task/DAG that
> created the XCom and when it should become visible. Any object that
> can be pickled can be used as an XCom value, so users should make sure
> to use objects of appropriate size.

In xCom a pythonoperator is used to call a function. That function pushes some values into a table called xcom in inside airflow metadata db. The same is then access via other DAGs or Tasks.

An example of how to do it all is here - https://www.cloudwalker.io/2020/01/28/airflow-xcom/